# running an application from another server

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have an application located in the server and the users need to use remote desktop connection to run this application from the server, and I am wondering if there is a way that the users can run the application from their computer without using remote desktop connection, I need this for security purpose because I don't the users to log in to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Remote Desktop Web Access](http://www.rdsgurus.com/working-with-rd-web-access-in-windows-server-2012/) service. It allows to publish only necessary application and users can access it throught browser without RDP connection directly to desktop of server.